# Trying To "Cookie-Free" A Sub-domain Using .htaccess, But Doesn't Work

Tags: caching, browser-cache, cache-control

Yes, I have searched a lot, here and there, and this is the closest I've found that I thought could actually work. But it doesn't.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|x-icon|js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|pdf)$">
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Pretty clear it should be that I am trying to cookie-free the static files served by a sub-domain, and remove the ETag header on those static files. The ETag thing works fine, but I am unable to unset the cookies.

FYI, Wordpress is installed on example.com (NOT www.example.com; www.example.com redirects to example.com), which is not cookie-free. And i.example.com serves the static files. I want to make i.example.com cookie-free. Is it at all possible to make a subdomain cookie-free when the non-www tld is not cookie-free? (I also see that it's the reason why many suggest using www.tld).

Answer (score 2):

Why you remove the ETag for this files? I would suggest to set this:

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

so the browsers, proxies, etc. knows, if a cached file was changed or not.
This speeds up the site a little bit on further visits.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you set the cookies in the request header so you have to use "RequestHeader unset Cookie" like so:

```html
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|x-icon|js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|pdf)$">
Header set Pragma "public"
Header append Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
RequestHeader unset Cookie
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why has this been -1 ?